# Refresh div using JQuery in Django while using the template system

Tags: django, jquery, django-views

I want to refresh a div tag in Django that contains temperature data. The data is fetched every 20 seconds. So far I have achieved this using these functions:

```
function refresh() {
$.ajax({
  url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
  success: function(data) {
  $('#test').html(data);
  }
});
};
$(function(){
    refresh();
    var int = setInterval("refresh()", 10000);
});
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('toolbox.monitor.views',
    url(r'^monitor-test/$', 'temperature', name="monitor-test"),
    url(r'^monitor/$', 'test', name="monitor"),
)
```

views.py:

```
def temperature(request):
  temperature_dict = {}
  for filter_device in TemperatureDevices.objects.all():
    get_objects = TemperatureData.objects.filter(Device=filter_device)
    current_object = get_objects.latest('Date')
    current_data = current_object.Data
    temperature_dict[filter_device] = current_data 
  return render_to_response('temp.html', {'temperature': temperature_dict})
```

temp.html has an include tag:

```
<table id="test"><tbody>
<tr>
{% include "testing.html" %}
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

testing.html just contains a for tag to iterate through the dictionary:

```
{% for label, value in temperature.items %}
      <td >{{ label }}</td>
      <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

The div is refreshed every 10 seconds and allows me to use the template system without patching it with js. However, I get repeated calls to '/monitor-test', 3-4 at the same time after a couple of minutes. Also, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this while being able to use the template system in Django. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I normally get around the 3-4 "concurrent" requests for such situations is to put the `setTimeout()` call inside the function I want to run repeatedly.

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
}

$(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

That makes it so every time the `refresh` function is called, it will automatically set itself to be called again in 10 seconds.  Another idea (if you still have problems) is to move the `setTimeout` into the success function in the AJAX call:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
            setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
        }
        
    });
}

$(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

That option might be a little bit sketchy if, for whatever reason, the AJAX call does not succeed.  But you can always get around that with other handlers, I suppose...

One suggestion I have (not particularly related to your question) is putting the whole `<table>` thing in the template that you render and return your `temperature` view. So, in your main template:

```
<div id="test">
{% include 'testing.html' %}
</div>
```

and in `testing.html`:

```
<table><tr>
{% for label, value in temperature.items %}
    <td>{{ label }}</td>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr></table>
```

Something about inserting part of a table the way you currently have it makes me want to cry :)  Sending a few more bytes over the wire in AJAX calls shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: Thanks! Althoug I tried both of the js functions it still requested 3-4 concurrent calls. I changed it to setTimeout and it worked out ok.

Comment: Doh!! That's what I had in mind when I was seeing/writing setInterval. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: If 'testing.html' has more content than the one on the question, the .js will be:

```
function refresh() {
$.ajax({
  url: '{% url monitor-test %}',
  success: function(data) {
  var dtr = $("#div_to_refresh", data);
  $('#div_to_refresh').html(dtr);
        }
    });
  setTimeout("refresh()", 3000);
}

$(function(){
    refresh();
});
```