# Django: Dynamic data in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

*HI!*

I want to make a page specifically Django that **when you click on the button** starts to throw numbers with an interval of 1 second and stop with other button, but **without reloading the page**, only the **section** of html.

I've been looking and I need to use ajax, but I do not understand many concepts of this technique, I begin to feel frustrated.

This is my overall idea.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 >Number of PI</h1>

    <!--Data-->
    <div style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px;">
        {{pi}}
    </div>

    <br>
    <!--Buttons-->
    <button>Start</button>
    <button>Stop</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import random

# Create your views here.
def base(request):
    context={"pi":str(random.random())}
    return render(request,"app/base.html",context)
```

This example works but I have to refresh the page
**THANKS!**

Comment: where is your ajax request ?

Comment: I never used ajax, I've been looking for some examples, but I do not understand some parts, you could guide me with a basic example? thanks

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776571/refresh-div-using-jquery-in-django-while-using-the-template-system Edit the question with your code if you find yourself stuck

Comment: thanks for example, in the line "url: '{% url%} monitor-test'," monitor-test is the name of the html view? which means that line?, thanks again

Comment: Yes. You need to make a few more changes (specific to your view)

Comment: You asked this before, or someone else following the same course did. There was by reason to use Ajax then, and there isn't now. You just need a simple javascript timer.