# Refreshing a specific div every few seconds in django using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to refresh the content of a table every few seconds in my HTML page using javascript. I keep getting 500 error when it tries to refresh the div, internal server error. Could someone enlighten the reason this is not working? I have used this: [Refresh div using JQuery in Django while using the template system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776571/refresh-div-using-jquery-in-django-while-using-the-template-system)
 as a reference to what I was doing. The page loads perfectly the first time just fails to refresh.

Here is my code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^specialScoreboard/$', views.specialScoreboard.as_view(), name='specialScoreboard'),
url(r'^specialScoreboardDiv/$', views.specialScoreboardDiv , name='specialScoreboardDiv'),
```

**views.py**

```
class specialScoreboard(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'CTF/specialScoreboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'teams'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(never_ever_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if getAnyActiveGame and request.user.is_staff:
            return super(specialScoreboard, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('CTF:no_active_game'))

    def get_queryset(self):
         """
            ordering teams by score
        """
        game = getAnyActiveGame()
        teams = get_teams_from_game(game)
        return sorted(teams, key=lambda a: a.get_score(game), reverse=True)

def specialScoreboardDiv():
    game = getAnyActiveGame()
    teams = get_teams_from_game(game)
    sortedList = sorted(teams, key=lambda a: a.get_score(game), reverse=True)
    return render_to_response('CTF/specialscoreboardDiv.html' , {'sortedList' :sortedList})
```

**scoreboardRefresh.js** + **scoreboardDiv.html**

```js
<script>
  var scoreboardURL = '{% url '
CTF: specialScoreboardDiv ' %}';

function refresh() {
  $.ajax({
    url: scoreboardURL,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#scoreboardDiv').html(data);
    }
  });
};
$(document).ready(function($) {
  refresh();
  setInterval("refresh()", 3000);
})

</script>
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">Scoreboard</div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="table-striped">
      <table id="scoreboardDiv" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Team Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for team in teams %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{team.name}}</td>
            <td>{{team|getScoreTeam}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to be able to format the error, here is a picture of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7Pj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoFOC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U73ei.jpg

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: What is going on with that `scoreboardURL` code at the start of your JS? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation in the views.py. Which methods are part of the class and which aren't?

Comment: Actually, looks like we need a text of server error.

Comment: I added a picture of the error, I can't seem to be able to format it, always looks unreadable.

Comment: you can see the server error in network section of chrome console.

Comment: I added another picture, its status is 500 type xhr

Comment: Sigh. You still haven't given us the actual error. Use the dev tools to open up the response itself and show us what it is.

Comment: @Alex Kipper you need the error from the django console. Or, if you can't get that console for some reason, you can click on `specialScoreboardDiv` the here: http://imgur.com/AWPxh0O

Comment: @Paul do you mean this: http://i.imgur.com/Gr7uKld.png ? sorry, I am very new at web development and might not understand what I am missing.

Comment: @Alex. It's ok. :) Yes, I mean this. But "Response" tab content is most interesting thing. Could you please show as what it contan?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QluqZyc.png

I think I understood the problem but not sure how to fix it, I have 
$('#scoreboardDiv').html(data);

in my script but my def specialScoreboardDiv() recives no argument, so makes sense its response is an error of too many arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your django view takes no arguments, but usually django tries to pass request param into it. From the error in the screenshot you provided in comments, looks likе this is your problem.

I think you error will be fixed by making your view function take this argument:

```
def specialScoreboardDiv(request):
    game = getAnyActiveGame()
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't error anymore but doesn't update the table content either :(

Comment: So, next you need to find out where is the problem. Does your view return the html it supposed to return? Does your JS get correct html? Does success callback ever fired? And so on.

Comment: Here is a picture of the data: http://i.imgur.com/IptrwHd.png in the ajax function, it does return the html of the correct div but does not update it. Am I missing something? The html page I am sending is the specialScoreboardDiv.html